# how to turn On/Off DND "Do not Disturb" Mode programmatically in iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift5

Is it possible to turn on/off "Do no disturb" for iPhone programmatically?

I am making an app in which I want to programmatically start Do Not Disturb feature in iOS. Can I able to fetch Do not disturb(DND) status from iPhone and Start DND from my app?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to manage DND status.  The user must change it themselves.

Comment: any other solution?